# python multithreading in windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-multithreading, system-tray

I'm trying to run the multiprocessing in windows. following is my code. #try 2 is working in linux.

```
class Login(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    # global path

    """
    Login user via the api
    Links the gui and the app functionality
    Logged user token is saved for further processing
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...

    # Do Login
    def doLogin(self):
        .....
        # try 1
        obj_my_cls = MyClass()
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.trayIcon.show())
        t.start()

        d = threading.Thread(target=obj_my_cls.checking_folder())
        d.start()

        # try 2
        d = Process(name='1daemon', target=self.trayIcon.show())
        d.daemon = False
        d.start()

        n = Process(name='2daemon', target=obj_my_cls.checking_folder())
        n.daemon = False
        n.start()
```

but it isn't working in windows 10. There is no system tray menu until checking_folder completed.

How could I do?